# Can struts2 deal file upload like servlet3?

Tags: java, struts2, servlet-3.0

html:

```
   <form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <input name="upload" type="file">  
    <input type="submit" value="upload">  
   </form>
```

servlet3:

```
@WebServlet("/upload")
@MultipartConfig
public class UploadFileServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public UploadFileServlet() {
    super();
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Part filePart = request.getPart("upload");
    String header = filePart.getHeader("Content-Disposition");
    String filename = header.substring(header.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10, header.lastIndexOf("\""));

    System.out.println(filename);
    InputStream in = filePart.getInputStream();

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:/temp.png");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length = -1;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();

    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doPost(request, response);
}
}
```

in this way, I can upload file successfully, but I'd like to deal it in struts2 the same way, code block below:

```
public void newTask() throws Exception {
    Part filePart = request.getPart("file");
    String header = filePart.getHeader("Content-Disposition");
    String _filename = header.substring(header.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10, header.lastIndexOf("\""));
    InputStream in = filePart.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D://temp.png");

    StreamUtils.copy(in, out);

}
```

but it doesn't work, I can't get anything from Part, it throw `NullPointException`, what should I do to change my code or it can't work in strut2 use the same way connect file with servlet3?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/docs/file-upload.html   If you want to handle file uploading yourself you need to exclude `fileUpload` interceptor.

Comment: Only one question: *why* ?

Comment: You can do it with struts as mentioned by @AleksandrM. I myself prefer to do it with struts, the struts upload interceptor has some useful features for example  some validations file validations can be configured easily . On the other hand the upload action is same as other actions and its quite logic that struts framework handle it for you. For example you may prefer that interceptors run before or after upload actions just as they do before other actions. Or you may need to access value stack or your message resources during upload action.

Comment: I have solve this problem successfully, thank you!

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.